# Cloud Firestore in Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I want to integrate the new Cloud Firestore to my Cloud Functions.

I updated node.js and installed the latest firebase version on my mac.

The Documentation says:

```
exports.myFunctionName = functions.firestore
  .document('users/marie').onWrite((event) => {
    // ... Your code here
 });
```

should work. I just copied the code and pasted it into the index.js, like every other realtime database functions. When I deploy the function code ($firebase deploy --only functions), i get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/zm/wp2415l929s472jv7kzbt3km0000gn/T/fbfn_21520Y4xqAJosBNHe/index.js:196:45)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

Any suggestions/ideas on the problem?

Comment: What version of `firebase-functions` do you have in your project? You should upgrade it to the latest, since Cloud Firestore was just released.

Comment: You probably have an old version of the SDK. Update it as [described in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#set_up_and_initialize_functions_sdk) by running `npm install firebase-functions@latest --save` in your project's functions directory

Comment: Already did that, but I tried again. Restarted my mac, but still the same error

Comment: I had to change my package.json to make it work.

Comment: @J.Doe. what did you change exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i tried all these things, but it didn't work out. But firebase brought out an update, now it works :)

Seems like they had some bugs with it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your package to:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.4.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And run a update after that in the terminal (npm update).

Answer (score 2):

Just calling `firebase init` did it for me. (this also changed the Package.json file)

Answer (score 1):

I went through the process of creating a brand new project in a new folder and it got rid of the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [firebase-documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).

> In many cases, new features and bug fixes are available only with the latest version of the Firebase CLI and **firebase-functions** SDK. It's a good practice to frequently update both the Firebase CLI and the SDK with these commands inside the **functions** folder of your Firebase project:

Always ensure you are using updated packages.

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```