# Firestore: "add is not a function"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I try to use Firestore in Cloud functions but I faced with error

> db.collection(...).doc(...).collection(...).doc(...).add is not a function at Promise

I read these topics [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696497/cloud-firestore-in-cloud-functions), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46892475/run-firestore-batch-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase) and other. But id didn't help me. The package.json looks

```
"firebase": "^4.3.1",
"firebase-admin": "^5.5.1",
"firebase-functions": "^0.7.5",
```

One of cloud functions

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var db = admin.firestore();
```

This code from function

```
const currentUserMatchProm = db.collection('userMatches').doc(currentUserID).collection('test').doc(matchID).add({
            'matchID': matchID,
            'matchedUserID': eventUserID,
            'timestamp': timestamp,
            'isActive': false
        });

        const eventUserMatchProm = db.collection('userMatches').doc(eventUserID).collection('test').doc(matchID).add({
            'matchID': matchID,
            'matchedUserID': currentUserID,
            'timestamp': timestamp,
            'isActive': false
        });
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`doc` is document, `add` function is only for collection. To write data to a document, use the `set` function:

```
doc(matchID).set({ ... })
```

Comment: [Documentation says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) "Behind the scenes, .add(...) and .doc().set(...) are completely equivalent, so you can use whichever is more convenient." but I do see where you _cannot_ do `.doc().add()`